# openapi 3.0: how to add examples of objects having nested objects inside it?

Tags: rest, yaml, swagger

I want to add examples of my response schema in openapi 3.0 YAML. I have went through the idea on link https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/ but my issue is that my response schema object contains nested objects inside it. Can anyone help and guide me about how to add example while having nested objects?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define a response example in two ways.
Let this is your nested json object response :

```
{
  "status": true,
  "data": {
    "storeId": "string",
    "message": "string"
  }
}
```

Method 1 : Here in parameter definition itself you can add the example

```
myschema:
      type: object
      properties:
        status:
          type: boolean
          required: true
          example: true
        data:
          type: object
          properties:
            "message":
              type: string
              example: Success
            "Id":
              type: string
              example: 1234
```

Method 2 : Here after the property definition you can define an `example:` tag like this

```
myschema:
      type: object
      properties:
        status:
          type: boolean
          required: true
        data:
          type: object
          properties:
            message:
              type: string
            Id:
              type: string
      example: 
    status: true
    data:
      Id: '1234'
      message: success
```